# mysql dont want results after variable assign

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, resultset, assignment-operator

I've got a stored procedure which does some assignments. When I run it each of the lines with a select/assignment with outputs a resultset. I just want one result set at the end of the procedure. For example, I have:

```sql
select @n := COUNT(id), @a := AVG(id) FROM deletemelater;
```

which returns a resultset, but I just want to use the variables later in the script and I don't want any output at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
-- select @n := COUNT(id), @a := AVG(id) FROM deletemelater;

SELECT COUNT(`id`), AVG(`id`) INTO @`n`, @`a`
FROM `deletemelater`;

SELECT @`n`, @`a`;
```

Comment: Thanks wchiquiti, I just came back to post that as the answer after sleeping on it. I normally SQL Server and I'm just getting my head around the various difference between that and MySQL. Problem solved as they say.